# Automatically saving the operation through passing the command line argument

Tags: c++, qt-creator, c++14

I already have a save function in my tool as like a normal tools. Now I would like to add auto save function, that has to save all the operation that made in the tool(we called that overlays) without pressing ctrl+S, have to  done automatically. I need to write an auotsave function and I have to pass as command line arguments. Could some one will help me out. More detail: When I right to open my tool in Linux, mostly we used to pass like cd home/...bla bla../ and ToolName. I need to use the autosave function as command line arguments. for eg: When I pass the argument as -s for automatically saving function when I try to pass like........ ToolName -s......... it has to save the data or operation automatically which is performed in my tool. looking for your valuable answers

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    const std::string OPT = "-A";
    bool hasOption =  false;
    for ( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i ) {
        if ( OPT == argv[i] ) {
              hasOption = true;
              break;
        }
    }

    if ( hasOption ) {

    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @TobySpeight you can go through my code outline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only this argument, you can use the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
//...
  // argv[0] contains the program name
  if(argc >= 2 && strncmp(argv[1], "-s", 2){
    // start a thread that saves and sleeps in a loop
  }
//...
return 0;
}
```

Otherwise you have to loop through the arguments like:

```
int i;
for(i=1; i<argc; ++i){
  if(strncmp(argv[i], "-s", 2){
     // start a thread that saves and sleeps in a loop
  }
}
```

There are also libraries for argument parsing but i doubt that you need it for only one argument.

Comment: Thanks for your answer its really helpful. But I am struck in how can I set the argument to my save function and it has to save the operation automatically @akg

Comment: You need to pass a filename for it? If yes, then check if argc is big enough and just pass `argv[2]` or `argv[i+1]` as parameter. I assume you can simply call your save function, so if you start a thread and just call it in n seconds, it can work (obviously save should be threadsafe).

Comment: I have a save function like noraml tool (Ctrl +S). I have a command line argument that is defined as (-A). I have to use this -A to perform the save function automatically. If I pass the command in Linux for eg: " ToolName -A ". It has to save the operation that has been made in thetool. what would be the easiest way to perform auto save. @akg